# JavaFX How to change the default function of shortcut key?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Two buttons are in VBox. If click the first button, then press "TAB", the focus frame will move to the second button. So my question is, if I wanna use the "TAB" for other function,how can I change or cancel or prevent the default function of "TAB" in JavaFX?

```
Button btn1 = new Button("First Button");
Button btn2 = new Button("Second Button");
VBox root = new VBox();
root.getChildren().addAll(btn1,btn2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use one of the setOnKeyPressed/Released/Typed method. And then do your magic. For example just consume it, to prevent the switching between buttons.

```
    btn1.setOnKeyPressed(e->{
        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {
            e.consume();
        }
    });
```